# SQL Query - Array but Specific Column only show 1 time

Tags: php, mysql, twig

Model

```
$sql = "
SELECT  op.name 
     , op.price 
     , op.quantity 
     , o.order_cancel_remark  
  FROM order_product op 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `order` o 
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `order_product_history` oph 
    ON oph.`order_product_id` = op.`order_product_id` 
   AND oph.`current_status` = 1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `order_status` os 
    ON os.`order_status_id` = oph.`order_status_id` 
   AND os.`language_id` = 1 
 WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

return $query->rows;
```

Controller

```
    $data['orderP_results'][] = array(

        'name'      => $order_price_result['name'] ,
        'price'     => number_format($order_price_result['map'],2,'.',''),
        'quantity'  => $order_price_result['quantity'],
        'sku'       => $order_price_result['sku'],
         'order_cancel_remark'      => $order_price_result['order_cancel_remark'],
        'total'     => number_format($order_price_result['map'] * $order_price_result['quantity'],2,'.',''),

    );
```

View Page

```
     {% if orderP_results %}
            {% for orderP_result in orderP_results %}
              {{orderP_result.order_cancel_remark}}
            <table class="d">
            <tr>
                <th>        <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product Image</legend></th>
                <th>    <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product Name</legend></th>
                <th>        <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product SKU</legend></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>    <img src="{{orderP_result.image}}"></td>
                    <td>    <b class="color-bold">{{orderP_result.name}}</b> </td>
                        <td>        SKU: <b class="color-bold">{{orderP_result.sku}}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

View Page : https://prnt.sc/rwghyo

What i wanted : For "Order Cancel Remark" is only showing 1 time instead of multiple time ( depending on rows )

Example ( this is what i wanted ) : https://prnt.sc/rwgi8u

Comment: Why not only output the order cancel remark on the first row. Use a boolean, set it to false. In the loop, if the boolean is false, output the order cancel remark and set the boolean to true.

Comment: @ryantxr  thanks for the reply , but wanted to ask , how does "Use a boolean, set it to false. In the loop, if the boolean is false, output the order cancel remark and set the boolean to true" works ?

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`, and there's no point LEFT JOINing tables from which you select no columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, your query is functionally identical to the following:

```
SELECT  op.name 
 , op.price 
 , op.quantity 
 , o.order_cancel_remark  
  FROM order_product op  
  JOIN `order` o 
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
  WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, remove the order_cancel_remark from the for loop and add it outside for displaying it only once

```
{% if orderP_results %}
            {{orderP_result[0].order_cancel_remark}}
            {% for orderP_result in orderP_results %}
            <table class="d">
            <tr>
                <th>        <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product Image</legend></th>
                <th>    <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product Name</legend></th>
                <th>        <legend style="padding-top:10px;">Product SKU</legend></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>    <img src="{{orderP_result.image}}"></td>
                    <td>    <b class="color-bold">{{orderP_result.name}}</b> </td>
                        <td>        SKU: <b class="color-bold">{{orderP_result.sku}}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: after follow your code , the "result " are unable to show :https://prnt.sc/rwiz9k

Comment: Your {{order cancel remark}} is printing the value Order cancel remark, you can either change it there, if there is issue you face